# MVVM duplicated code in multiple Repositories

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel

I have multiple repositories who needs some credentials to work with an external service. Those credentials are stored in the Shared Preferences of my app and I successfully load it in every repository.

To specify those credentials are used in the SOAP header request and they are provided by the user.

With the current solution I load those creds in the activities and then pass down to the repository through a method in the viewmodels. This approch generates a lot of duplicated code, since for each activity where I need those creds I repeat the whole process.

Is there any better solution that will follow the MVVM best practices and avoid duplicate code?

Comment: Extract out the duplicated code and provide that as a dependency.  Your credentials could easily be extracted behind another class that is reused, that way this new class has a single responsibility and abstracts how the credentials are provided.  I'm not a fan of needless utils classes that have `static` methods as it makes it harder to test.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more context?

In my opinion there is no general answer without knowing more about your application. Does these repositories use the same service (e.g. network service?). If so, you could add them as an custom Interceptor.

You could inject them in an abstraction layer behind the repositories.

Why do you store the credentials in shared preferences? Are they static (like network api keys you got from the api)? If so, you could put them e.g. in gradle.properties and save them as BuildConfig Field

Comment: I tried to rewrite a question maybe is more specific now.

Comment: if you use OkHttpClient i would suggest to use an Interceptor (https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/)

Then it is up to you, if you use dependency injection, inject your shared preferences to the Interceptor. If not, just pass it on your own (one-time)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid redundant code, one thing you can do is write that code in an utility class and use that in your repositories. 
Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write one POJO class which will hold the credentials. In your Main activity create one object with the creds and then just send this object across the application as needed.